# C program for aggregate marks and percentage

Tags: c

> If the marks obtained by a student in five different subjects are input through the keyboard, write a program to find out the aggregate marks and percentage marks obtained by the student. Assume that the maximum marks that can be obtained by a student in each subject is 100.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5, aggregate_marks;
    float percentage_marks;
    printf("Enter the marks of sub1: ");
    printf("\nEnter the marks of sub2: ");
    printf("\nEnter the marks of sub3: ");
    printf("\nEnter the marks of sub4: ");
    printf("\nEnter the marks of sub5: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d",&sub1, &sub2, &sub3, &sub4, &sub5);
    aggregate_marks = sub1+sub2+sub3+sub4+sub5;
    printf("Aggregate marks is: %d",aggregate_marks);
    percentage_marks = (aggregate_marks/500)*100;
    printf("\nPercentage marks is: %f\n",percentage_marks);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the marks of sub1: 

Enter the marks of sub2: 

Enter the marks of sub3: 

Enter the marks of sub4: 

Enter the marks of sub5: 78

54

67

87

75

Aggregate marks is: 361

Percentage marks is: 0.000000
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

The input marks are not aligned with subjects and percentage marks aren't showing.
What is wrong here?

Comment: Integer division yields an integer result - `1/2 == 0`.  Instead of dividing `aggregate_marks` by `500`, divide it by `500.0f` - that will force floating-point division, and you'll get a floating-point result.

Comment: They are not aligned becuase you printed every prompt before getting any inputs. You could have `scanf("%d", &sub1);` after the first prompt, similar for the others.

Comment: *"percentage marks aren't showing"* - You never told it to print one.  Note that `%` is a special character in `printf`, you have to escape it with another `%` (e.g. `printf("\nPercentage marks is: %f%%\n", percentage_marks);`

Comment: @0x5453 good point, I was going to say that but realised that "percentage marks aren't showing" means the marks, not the signs.

Comment: percentage marks is showing, Thanks!!

Comment: printf("Enter the marks of sub1: \nsub2: \nsub3: \nsub4: \nsub4: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d",&sub1, &sub2, &sub3, &sub4, &sub5);  I tried this to align the input with subjects but still not aligned

Comment: @AshfiRahman: `scanf` and `printf` do *line-oriented* input and output - you're not going to get your prompts and inputs to magically line up on the screen in this manner.  You'll have to print the first prompt, get the first input, *then* print the second prompt, get the second input, etc.  Think in terms of working in front of an old-school line printer or teletype, not a 2D screen.

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat:* This isn't a direct answer to your problem, but I want you to get off on a good footing. It could/should be a comment except for the code refactoring.

When you use `sub1, sub2, ...`, this "cries out" for an array implementation (e.g.):

```
int subs[5];
```

And, a loop instead of separate `printf/scanf` pairs for each *scalar* value.

When starting out in programming, it isn't always easy to see the use case for an array. It might have been [more] obvious if you had to enter a much larger number of marks (e.g. 1000).

Anyway, here's a version of your code that implements an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SUBMAX      5

int
main(void)
{
    int idx;
    int curmark;
    int subs[SUBMAX];
    int aggregate_marks = 0;
    float percentage_marks;

    for (idx = 0;  idx < SUBMAX;  ++idx) {
        printf("Enter the marks of sub%d: ",idx + 1);
        fflush(stdout);

        scanf(" %d",&curmark);
        subs[idx] = curmark;

        aggregate_marks += curmark;
    }

    printf("Aggregate marks is: %d\n", aggregate_marks);

    percentage_marks = (aggregate_marks / 500.0) * 100;
    printf("Percentage marks is: %f%%\n", percentage_marks);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm just a beginner and this is first chapter program.

Comment: Actually, if this is your first program, and you haven't got to arrays yet, you can eliminate the array because the aggregate doesn't depend on it. You could comment out the lines that use `subs`. It's only if you needed to retain the individual marks, that you'd need an array. If _that_ was part of the problem definition, the book should have explained the arrays first.

Answer (score 0):

**Input marks are not aligned because** you first print all the 5 *printf* statements and then execute *scanf* for 5 inputs. To resolve this issue you can *first use one *printf* statements and then execute scanf for 1 subject*. Ex:

```
printf("Enter the marks of first subject(out of 100): ");
scanf("%f",&sub1);
```

**Percentage marks are not showing because** in C if two variables or constants are integer then any mathematical operation between them yeilds an integer.
In your case

```
percentage_marks = (aggregate_marks/500)*100;
```

1. First (aggregate_marks/500) operation executes. If we take your input then
   aggregate_marks = 361 and (361/500) = 0.722 but as 361 and 500 both are integer it yields 0.
2. Second Operation (0 * 100) yeilds 0. But when it initializes to percentage_marks as it is a float it promoted from int to float and percentage_marks = 0.000000.

To resolve this issue you need to take all subject marks and aggregate_marks float. Ex:

```
float sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4,sub5;
float total, aggregate_marks, percentage_marks;
```

After making those changes your code looks like:

```
//program to calculate the aggregate and percentage marks of a student
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        float sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4,sub5;
        float total, aggregate_marks, percentage_marks;

        printf("Enter the marks of first subject(out of 100): ");
        scanf("%f",&sub1);

        printf("Enter the marks of second subject(out of 100): ");
        scanf("%f",&sub2);

        printf("Enter the marks of third subject(out of 100): ");
        scanf("%f",&sub3);

        printf("Enter the marks of fourth subject(out of 100): ");
        scanf("%f",&sub4);

        printf("Enter the marks of fifth subject(out of 100): ");
        scanf("%f",&sub5);

        aggregate_marks = (sub1 + sub2 + sub3 + sub4 + sub5);   // formula to calculate aggregate marks
        percentage_marks = (aggregate_marks / 500) * 100;       // formula to calculate percentage marks

        printf("Aggregate marks: %.2f\n", aggregate_marks);
        printf("Percentage marks: %.2f\n", percentage_marks);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you can use 'Enter the marks of sub1:' in scanf itself for eg-

```
    scanf("Enter the marks of sub1: %d\n",&sub1);
```

For your percentage calculations you should multiply the aggregate by 100 first and then divide it by zero because when you divide 361 by 500 it should give 0.722 but in C it treats this as integer and round off as 0.
Here's the right code-

```
    percentage_marks = (aggregate_marks*100)/500;
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: You cannot print the prompt using `scanf`.